# Passing constexpr objects around

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I decided to give then new `C++14` definition of `constexpr` a spin and to get the most out of it I decided to write a little compile-time string parser. However, I'm struggling with keeping my object a `constexpr` while passing it to a function. Consider the following code:

```c++
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

class str_const {
    const char * const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const( const char( & a )[ N ] )
    : p_( a ), sz_( N - 1 ) {}
    constexpr char operator[]( std::size_t n ) const {
        return n < sz_ ? p_[ n ] : throw std::out_of_range( "" );
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz_; }
};

constexpr long int numOpen( const str_const & str ){
    long int numOpen{ 0 };
    std::size_t idx{ 0 };
    while ( idx <  str.size() ){
        if ( str[ idx ] == '{' ){ ++numOpen; }
        else if ( str[ idx ] == '}' ){ --numOpen; }
        ++idx;
    }
    return numOpen;
}

constexpr bool check( const str_const & str ){
    constexpr auto nOpen = numOpen( str );
    // ...
    // Apply More Test functions here,
    // each returning a variable encoding the correctness of the input
    // ...

    return ( nOpen == 0 /* && ... Test the variables ... */ );
}

int main() {
    constexpr str_const s1{ "{ Foo : Bar } { Quooz : Baz }" };
    constexpr auto pass = check( s1 );
}
```

I uses the [`str_const` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) presented by [Scott Schurr at C++Now 2012](http://2012.cppnow.org/session/cpp11-new-tools-for-class-and-library-authors/) in a version modified for `C++14`.

The above code will fail to compile with the error (`clang-3.5`)

```
error: constexpr variable 'nOpen' must be initialized by a constant expression  
    constexpr auto nOpen = numOpen( str );  
                           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Which leads me to the conclusion that you can not pass around a `constexpr` object without losing its `constexpr`-ness. This lead me to the following questions:

1. Is my interpretation correct?
2. Why is this the behaviour the standard dictates?

   I don't see the problem in passing a `constexpr` object around. Sure, I could rewrite my code to fit into a single function, but that leads to cramped code. I would assume that factoring separate functionality into separate units of code (functions) should be good style for compile time operations too.
3. As I said before the compiler error can be solved by moving the code from the bodies of separate testing functions (such as `numOpen`) into the body of the *top-level* function `check`. However, I don't like this solution since it creates one huge and cramped function. Do you see a different approach to solving the problem?

Comment: *Do you see a different approach to solving the problem?* `constexpr auto nOpen = numOpen( str );` instance doesn't need to be `constexpr` to evaluate the function at compile time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that **inside** a `constexpr` function, **parameters aren't constant expressions**, regardless of whether the arguments are. You can call `constexpr` functions inside others, but the parameters of a `constexpr` function aren't `constexpr` *inside*, making any function call (even to `constexpr` functions) not a constant expression - *inside*.

```
const auto nOpen = numOpen( str );
```

[**Suffices**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e965abb6a6534432). Only once you view the call from *outside* the `constexpr`-ness of the expressions inside is verified, deciding whether the whole call is `constexpr` or not.

Comment: I guess this means that it is not possible to create a `constexpr` object inside a function from a string literal passed to that function? Which is a shame since I wanted to wrap the `check` function inside my actual parser. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/CuG37r45) (non-compiling) mock-up code.