# char pointer initialization compared to non pointer? What happens

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char

I know you cant do this with a normal char.

```
    char line1 = "hello";
```

but you can do this with a pointer to a char type

```
    char* line2 = "hello";
```

I wanted to know why this is, what happens in the second line of code? 
Why is the second initialization possible? Is line2 pointing to the first index of hello? does it create some kind of array and fill it in with hello? I used this in a c string class for a programming class and I am still confused about what goes on in the second line of code.

Comment: It would be nice to mark the answer that helped you as accepted, you know... site rules and all that stuff like "be nice to others"..

Comment: Do not edit your question to state it has been answered, but accept the answer.

Comment: And pick a language. C is not C++ and vice-versa.

Comment: and watch out for the `char* line2 = "hello";` this is dangerous because it's assigning a constant string to a non constant pointer. Writing to that pointer later will likely cause the program to go boom with a memory access error. C++ will complain and using that sort of trick in a function call can result in some interesting compiler error messages of the "No function overload for parameter X" type.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler ensures that the null-terminated string"hello" you specified exists somewhere in memory, and initializes the pointer to point to the beginning of that string.

Comment: Is this sort of what the strcpy() function would do?..besides making a pointer point to it. It does not place it on the heap though since it doesn't use "new". So it only "exists" temporary while the function where it is runs? or something like that.

Comment: No, it is not. The compiler is free to decide where it puts this string, however it is usually done through the Operating System facilities. Specifically, the string is embedded into the executable and loaded by the OS into memory. The compiler then just makes the pointer point to that piece of memory.

Comment: It's worth noting that changing the characters of that string is __undefined behavior__. That's why (at least in C++), converting string literals to `char*` is deprecated. You should always use `const char*` when initializing pointers with string literals.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
char *line1 = "something";
```

`line1` is created as a pointer on the stack (if in the automatic scope) and gets initialized to point to the literal string `"something"` (with a null terminator). To be precise the `"something"` string has type `char[10]` including the null terminator and the array [decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to the first element in this particular instance.

The data where that string is stored is the data section of your compiled executable and it is **read-only** (i.e. writing to it would probably trigger an access violation).

Comment: I don't think that the literal is necessarily created on the stack. When the executable is loaded into memory, the pointer probably just points to the location of the string.

Comment: I never wrote that a literal is created on the stack. I wrote `The data where that string is stored is the data section of your compiled executable`

Comment: No worries! Glad we straightened that out

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, when you make a string literal, there is implicitly created a variable of type `char[]` with static storage duration to hold it. The string will be null-terminated as is consistent with C style.

The line

```
char* line2 = "hello";
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
static char __string_literal_line2[] = "hello";
// At top of program or something

...
char * line2 = __string_literal_line2;
```

So the `char[]` implicitly decays to a `char*` when you do it this way.

A wrinkle in this is that the array really is "const" in some sense and it is undefined behavior to try to modify it, but the C standard explicitly permits you to assign it to a `char *` anyways, so that legacy code that is not const-correct will still compile, and to be compatible C++ also permits this.

It's sometimes really convenient if you are doing compile-time programming to take advantage of the "true form" of the string literal. For instance in this code sample:

[Passing constexpr objects around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around)

```
class str_const {
    const char * const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const( const char( & a )[ N ] )
    : p_( a ), sz_( N - 1 ) {}

    ...
};
```

The `str_const` object can now be constructed as a constexpr at compile time from a string literal, and it will know the size of the string literal, even though normally you need to iterate or use C library functions to determine that. That's because it receives the string literal as a `char[]` rather than as a `char *`, and it can bind to the length of the array as part of the template deduction. So these expressions are legal, and the `str_const` object knows the lengths of the strings at compile-time:

```
str_const("foo");
str_const("foobar");
str_const("foobarbaz");
```

Comment: "C explicitly permits you..." should probably be accompanied with some sort of cautionary text, since it's a hack so that const-incorrect legacy code doesn't need to be updated, rather than a feature that new code should use. (and IIRC it only works with *literals*; your example code shouldn't compile)

Answer (score 0):

```
char test[] = "Hello" // adds H e l l o \0 in the stack
```

When you do someting like f("Hello"), it reserves memory to store H e l l O \0
When you do

```
char *test = "Hello";
```

It stores Hello too somewhere and initialize test to the memory case where the 'H' is stored.

Basically pointers are 4 bytes integers. You should try to a program asking a password and verifying like this :

```
if(password == "mypassword")
```

and your job is to find "mypassword" in the generated binary.

Comment: Oh I see what where I got messed up, I forgot that line1 would need to be an array of characters......... that's why it doesn't work lol. I was overthinking and brought memory into it. Does the pointer create a static memory variable?

Comment: "Basically pointers are 4 bytes integers" — usually 8 bytes nowadays, but that's not defined by the standard so you should not count on it.