# How to use constexpr function with reference parameters in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm learning about `constexpr` function recently, and I write a function to check if two strings are the same object by examining their address (just for curiosity). The function compiled correctly, but it seems some problem happened when I try to call that function.

Theoretically, the function will return a constant expression if its arguments are constant expressions, otherwise, it will act like a normal function. So in the first part of the code, I try to call the function with const variables. In the second part, I call the function with nonconst variables.

Below is my code. I use Visual Studio Community 2015. The compiler warned me with two errors that I marked with `^` below, but the code can still be compiled and run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr bool isSameString(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2) {
    return &s1 == &s2;
}

int main() {
    //constexpr std::string s("p");  // No constexpr constructor
    static const std::string s1("a");
    static const std::string s2("a");
    static const std::string s3("b");

    // Right return value in editor, wrong when running.
    constexpr bool b1 = isSameString(s1, s1);

    // Error in editor(but can still compile), wrong when running.
    constexpr bool b2 = isSameString(s1, s2);
                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error

    // Error in editor(but can still compile), wrong when running.
    constexpr bool b3 = isSameString(s1, s3);
                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error

    std::cout << b1 << " " << b2 << " " << b3 << std::endl;

    /********************************************************************/

    std::string s4("x");
    std::string s5("x");
    std::string s6("y");

    std::cout << isSameString(s4, s4) << " "         // Right return value
              << isSameString(s4, s5) << " "         // Right return value
              << isSameString(s4, s6) << std::endl;  // Right return value

    std::cin.get();
}
```

So,

1. Are there any ways to fix these two errors?
2. Why is the code can still be compiled and run with these errors?
3. Why the value of `b1` is different between in editor and when running?
4. Are there any ways to correctly call the function that return a `constexpr`?

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me :)

**EDIT**

I know that the `std::string` is not a literal type, but a reference is a literal type. And the question is about how to use `constexpr` *function*. So I think it's not duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306).

Comment: The string parameters are provided at runtime, so how can this form a `constexpr` evaluated/deduced at compile time?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So there is no possible way to do things related with `std::string` (or other non-literal type) at compile time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use std::string in a constexpr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306/is-it-possible-to-use-stdstring-in-a-constexpr)

Comment: @Jaege: You can do things with some non-literal types at compile time, but `std::string` doesn't have any `constexpr` constructors so you can't use it at compile time.

Comment: @Jaege: You may want to look at this one also, for the `str_const` object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around

Comment: @ChrisBeck : A.k.a `boost::string_ref` or `std::experimental::string_view`.