# constexpr literal initialization with a constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

simple example here:

```
 static constexpr const char literal1[] = "abcde"; 
 static constexpr const char literal2[] = literal1;
```

compilation error. How to make it work and why it doesn't?

Comment: Arrays cannot be initialized from other arrays. (String literals are an exception.)

Comment: [This](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gM5T1bdeqCNItFdI) is the best I can think of.

Comment: You could also use the `str_const` template from Scott Schurr's Boost Con slides, I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around

Answer (score 4):

update:

In response to comment, here's a revised verson.

The class `immutable::string` models a constexpr string-like object which tracks the original string literal. It's very similar to c++17's `string_view` except that the template constructor avoids the need for a call to `strlen` at any time.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace immutable {

    struct string
    {
        template<std::size_t N>
        constexpr string(const char (&s)[N])
        : _data(s)
        , _size(N-1)
        {}

        constexpr const char* data() const { return _data; }
        constexpr std::size_t size() const { return _size; }

        const char* const _data;
        const std::size_t _size;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, string s)
    {
        return os.write(s.data(), s.size());
    }
}


static constexpr auto literal1 = immutable::string("abcde");
static constexpr auto literal2 = literal1;

int main()
{
    std::cout << literal1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << literal2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are changing the actual type of `literal2`. I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @skypjack how can we know what he wants? He hasn't said.

Comment: @skypjack updated example for give a more consistent feel.

Comment: Chapeau. :-) ... Thank you. +1

Comment: @skypjack de rien! À votre service :-)

Comment: unfortunately I don't want to change a type. However the answer is in a comment by Kerrek SB. So no possible to do it with an array I have to use std::array.