# Is there any way for compile-time check of string user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I'm writing a user-defined `string` literal to convert names of months into their numbers. The expected usage of this literal is something like

```
"Nov"_m
```

which should return `11`.

At the moment my code looks like

```
constexpr Duration operator ""_m(const char* str, size_t len)
{
    return convert_month_to_int(str, len);
}
```

where `constexpr int convert_month_to_int(const char, size_t)` is a function which does the actual conversion (or returns `-1` if the month name is incorrect).

The problem is that I would like to show some kind of compile error if the string passed to this literal does not name any month. I tried using `static_assert` in the following way:

```
constexpr Duration operator ""_m(const char* str, size_t len)
{
    static_assert(convert_month_to_int(str, len) > 0, "Error");
    return convert_month_to_int(str, len);
}
```

but this does not work since the compiler is not sure that `convert_month_to_int(str, len)` will be a constant expression.

Is there any way of achieving this behavior?

Comment: gcc has extension to use template method here.

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean the variadic template user-defined literals? Aren't they for integer and floating-point types only?

Comment: Sorry for being stupid (the deleted answer) and all, but really, with just a small set of valid month identifiers, why not make it an `enum`? Because that's what `enum`s are for. Naming values, making a type out of it.

Comment: From standard, yes, but gcc has extension for c-string too, which would allow to do your check, but it is an extension.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I already have literals for years, months as a number, days, etc., and I'm able to enter the date like this: `2016_y + "Aug"_m + 6_d + 12_h + 50_min`. I think, usage of `enum`s here would be less pretty. Probably, if this question has no good answer, I'll switch to `enum`s.

Comment: How would that handle leap years?

Comment: @Dani Not sure I understand you. Leap years should be handled inside the `operator +`

Comment: `enum { Jan_m, Feb_m, ...` pretty!

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to make a function with parameters but using UDL syntax and `operator+`. Your example could be written as `make_date(2016, Aug, 6, 12, 50)`. The reason I think your way is flawed is because of questions like how much is March? 59 or 60? What is `2016_y + "Aug"_m + "December"_m`? It seems like there is only one way to order your expressions and you are better off with a function call.

Comment: With the gnu extension, it would be something like : [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bd7745439c9e741)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've approached this problem in a different way, using neither enums nor string literals, and bad month names are detected even when not constructed as `constexpr`:

```
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;
    auto m1 = nov;                           // ok
    static_assert(unsigned{nov} == 11, "");  // ok
    auto m2 = not_a_month;
    test.cpp:86:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'not_a_month'
        auto m2 = not_a_month;
                  ^
    1 error generated.
}
```

The approach I used is to define a [class type `month`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L259-L276) which is [documented to be a literal class type](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#month).

I then [create `constexpr` instances of each month](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L1645-L1656):

```
CONSTDATA date::month jan{1};
CONSTDATA date::month feb{2};
CONSTDATA date::month mar{3};
CONSTDATA date::month apr{4};
CONSTDATA date::month may{5};
CONSTDATA date::month jun{6};
CONSTDATA date::month jul{7};
CONSTDATA date::month aug{8};
CONSTDATA date::month sep{9};
CONSTDATA date::month oct{10};
CONSTDATA date::month nov{11};
CONSTDATA date::month dec{12};
```

(`CONSTDATA` is a macro to help compilers which aren't quite there with C++11 `constexpr` support limp along)

I also used the same technique for days of the week.

The above was all compiled using clang with `-std=c++11`.  It will also work with gcc.  The `constexpr` bits are broken in VS, but everything else works, including detecting bad month names at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with suggestion to use an enum instead.

But anyways, the usual way to signal an error like this in a `constexpr` function is to throw an exception.

```
constexpr Duration operator ""_m(const char* str, size_t len)
{
    return convert_month_to_int(str, len) > 0 ? convert_month_to_int(str, len) : throw "Error";
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around) for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will produce a compile-time error only when the result of `"NotAMonth"_m` is assigned to a `constexpr`.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 - that is: this will produce a compile-time error only when the error is detected at compile time; I don't know a way to impose a compile-time error when the error is detected run-time

Comment: I don't see any solution to that unfortunately. The issue is that in your operator `""` implementation, `const char * str` and `size_t len` are not constant expressions. (see, same question, [Columbo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around)). So I don't think you can use them in a `static_assert` condition. Unless you force the operator to run at compile-time, it will be too late to produce a compile-time error. The simplest thing is really to use an enum.