# Convert `hana::string` to `constexpr const char (&)[]`

Tags: c++, string, c++14, constexpr, boost-hana

I have some old code that uses something very similar to `str_const` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291903/passing-constexpr-objects-around) and [here](https://gist.github.com/creative-quant/6aa863e1cb415cbb9056f3d86f23b2c4) to do some constexpr string manipulation. `str_const` is a literal type described by Scott Schurr that can be constructed from a string literal, because it has a template constructor from `const char (&)[]`.

I now also have some new code using `boost::hana`.

I would like to be able to take a `hana::string` and create a `str_const` that refers to it. The simplest way to do this is to convert a `hana::string` to a `constexpr const char (&)[]`. (Actually, at this point that's not the simplest way, the simplest way is surely to add a new template constructor to my `str_const` implementation. But at this point the question has taken on a life of it's own and I'm mainly interested in whether this can be done with `hana::string`. So let's assume that I'm not allowed to change the `str_const` implementation.)

However, in `hana` [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html) the way to convert `hana::string` to a run-time string is `hana::to<const char *>`.

Optimistically, I tried various forms of `hana::to<const char (&)[hana::length(...)]> (...)` but this causes static assertions in `hana` to fail.

The other option suggested by `hana` docs is to use `hana::unpack` and then stick the characters in an array myself. I wrote this code

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct array {
  T arr[N];
};

struct char_packer {
  template <typename... Ts>
  constexpr auto operator()(Ts... ts) -> array<const char, sizeof...(ts) + 1> {
    return array<const char, sizeof...(ts) + 1>{{ ts... , 0 }};
  }
};

template <typename S>
struct string_keeper {
  static constexpr auto my_array = hana::unpack(S{}, char_packer{});
};

template <int N>
using char_arr = const char [N];

template <typename S>
constexpr auto to_string_literal(S &&) -> const char_arr<decltype(hana::length(S{}))::value + 1> & {
  return string_keeper<S>::my_array.arr;
}
```

I think this almost works, at least it compiles. But if the references are also used at run-time then it fails with a linker error: `undefined reference to ... string_keeper<boost::hana::string<(char)97> >::my_array`.

(Actually I think I understand why that's an ODR problem and if I think on it a bit longer I might remember how to fix it... not sure...)

Intuitively, I feel that there must be a way to do this. Because, `hana` already allows me to convert `hana::string` to `constexpr const char *` where the pointer points to exactly the array I want. In fact it even suggests that there's might be an evil option where I try to coerce the `const char *` back to `(&)[]` type, although that also seems like it would require doing things that won't be allowed in `constexpr` functions. Anyways if `hana` can make that array then surely I can too, or somehow convince it to give it to me more exactly.

Is there a way to fix my code above? Is there an easier way to do this within `hana` that I overlooked? Is this actually impossible for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other problem is that, when returned from a function, a raw char array will be decayed to a pointer. I would suggest constructing the `str_const` object in the context of your function which I believe fulfills your intent of creating `str_const` without changing its interface.

The following example uses a top level variable template to create the array which is what the `hana::string` implementation uses:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

class str_const {
    const char * const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const( const char( & a )[ N ] )
    : p_( a ), sz_( N - 1 ) {}
    constexpr char operator[]( std::size_t n ) const {
        return n < sz_ ? p_[ n ] : throw std::out_of_range( "" );
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz_; }
};

template <char ...c>
constexpr char string_storage[sizeof...(c) + 1] = {c..., '\0'};

struct to_str_const_helper {
  template <typename ...Ts>
  constexpr auto operator()(Ts...) {
    return str_const(string_storage<Ts::value...>);
  }
};
template <typename S>
constexpr auto to_str_const(S) {
  return hana::unpack(S{}, to_str_const_helper{});
}

int main()
{
  constexpr str_const str = to_str_const("foo"_s);
  static_assert(str[0] == 'f', "");
  static_assert(str[1] == 'o', "");
  static_assert(str[2] == 'o', "");
}
```

Comment: this answer insired me to cast from hana tuple into something like T (&)[N] for some ctor func. amazing!